# Cargar datos en Textbox desde Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Quiero cargar datos de una fila que al seleccionarla por medio de un botón los cargue en un formato.
Para esto lo estoy haciendo con el CommandName, cómo si fueran coordenadas, si hace clic en tal fila cargará estos datos y asi para todas.
Pero no sé como hacer en rows y cells con textbox.

```
   if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "clic") {

       int indexrow = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
       int id = (int)this.gvbuscar.DataKeys[indexrow]["Id"];
```

Comment: porque defines como tag de la consulta web-api? entiendo que seria simplemente asp.net ese tag estaria de mas

Answer (score 1):

Para poder asignar los campos del `DataGridView` a `TextBox` tienes que hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Creando una función que llene los `TextBox`

```
public static void LlenarTextBox(int IndiceDGV)
{
   TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows[IndiceDGV].Cells[0].Value.ToString(); //TextBox1 = Ap.Paterno
   TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.Rows[IndiceDGV].Cells[1].Value.ToString(); //TextBox2 = Ap.Materno
   TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.Rows[IndiceDGV].Cells[2].Value.ToString(); //TextBox3 = Nombre
}
```

`IndiceDGV` vendría siendo el índice actual de la fila que deseas seleccionar en el `DataGridView`. Luego se llama a la función en el evento `Click` de cada botón de la siguiente forma:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LlenarTextBox(0);
}
```

En este caso se manda el cero (`0`) indicando la primera fila.

Para hacer el código más homogéneo pudieras hacer lo siguiente:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LlenarTextBox(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);
}
```

Pero no estoy seguro si al hacer click en el botón esta propiedad se llena.

Comment: me sirvio poniendolo desde el double click del datagriview..gracias.saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para seleccionar un registro en el gridview tienes que usar el DataKeyNames y DataKeys

[[ASP.NET] GridView – Edición Empleados](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2011/05/aspnet-gridview-edicion-empleados.html)

Analiza en el articulo:

- Como se define el grid el nombre del campo que identifica a la entidad en el DataKeyNames
- La definicion del CommandName = "Select" para que ejecute el evento SelectedIndexChanging

La forma de tomar el valor seleccionado

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(NombreGrid.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value);
```

con esto puede redireccionar a otra pantalla para editar la entidad